# Dynamically added userform textbox control _click event not firing ? (but _change works) (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm trying to get the _click event to work on a dynamically added textbox control on a userform.

Here is my code, it gets the _change events just fine but the _click event do not fire.

```
' Userform code
Dim myControlsEventH As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set myControlsEventH = New Collection
End Sub

Public Sub AddTextbox(myName As String)

    'Dim MyTextBox As Object
    Dim myTextbox As MSForms.TextBox

    Set myTextbox = frmStamps.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", myName, True)

    myTextbox.TextAlign = 2
    myTextbox.Font.Size = 18
    myTextbox.WordWrap = False
    'MyTextBox.AutoSize = True
    AdjustSize

    Dim txtbxEvent As ctxtbxEventH
    Set txtbxEvent = New ctxtbxEventH
    Set txtbxEvent.frm = frmStamps
    Set txtbxEvent.txtbox = myTextbox

    myControlsEventH.Add txtbxEvent

End Sub

' ctxtbxEventH Class code
Public WithEvents txtbox As MSForms.TextBox
Public frm As UserForm

Private Sub txtbox_Click()
    Debug.Print "clicked"
End Sub

Private Sub txtbox_Change()
    Debug.Print "changed"
End Sub
```

(BONUS question (where can I find the list of all possible events for each of the MSForms controls ? ))

Comment: as side notes, you should consider using `with`. And i prefer using scripting.dictionary  for class events, because i can check if they exist, and remove them easily, because dictionaries have these functionalities. (and are faster)

Comment: Thanks, I never used With, I've seen it in many examples but I never investigated.  As for using scripting.dictionary, I never heard of that. It seems like an alternative to a Collection ? In this case I'm putting the eventhandler object in there so it doesn't vanish at the end of the execution of AddTextbox() but I don't refer to them again in the code.

Comment: for dictionary, see http://excelmacromastery.com/Blog/index.php/vba-dictionary/    . for dynamically deleting controls or checking their existence without need of `on error resume next` it's very usefull. Also note that you'd need to add a reference to MICROSOFT SCRIPTING RUNTIME, or add each time `set ObjectVar = CreateObject ("Scripting.Dictionary")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `MSForms.TextBox` has not a `Click` event. But a `MouseUP` event is available.

```
Private Sub txtbox_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Debug.Print "mouse up"
End Sub
```

You can have a list of possible events using the list in the Declarations/Procedure navigation box in the VBA Editor after set the needed object in the Object navigation box:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you answered both my questions at once !